# Did someone use ClickAndHoldAction, MoveMouseAction and ButtonReleaseAction methods as a replacement for drag and drop in Selenium?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, mouse, deprecated, selenium-webdriver

Searching for implementations of drag and drop in selenium I only found the deprecated methods
dragAndDropOn and dragAndDropBy.

Documentation says to use **ClickAndHoldAction, MoveMouseAction and ButtonReleaseAction** instead of the deprecated methods.

Don't know how to use them. Didn't found any good example. Did someone use these methods?
Maybe there are some better ways to drag and drop using selenium on Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u find http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions allready?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of Ivo leads to the right solution. However for your two methods there is a 'shortcut' in the framework. You do not actually need to use those actions one by one. You can use a convenience method.

For the removed WebElement.dragAndDropOn use

```
new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(...).build().perform();
```

For the removed WebElement.dragAndDropBy use

```
new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(...).build().perform();
```